# Accesing <td> elements in a table that do not have ID or class when using python and BeautifulSoup on html/css pages

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a page using Selenium, Python and Beautiful Soup, and I want to output the rows of a table as comma delimited values. Unfortunately the HTML of the page is all over the place. So far I have managed to extract two columns by using the IDs of their elements. The rest of the values are just contained in  without an identifier such as class or id. Here is a sample of the results.

```
<table id="tblResults" style="z-index: 102; left: 18px; width: 956px; 
   height: 547px" cellspacing="1" width="956" border="0">
   <tr style="color:Black;background-color:LightSkyBlue;font-family:Arial;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Select</td>
      <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResults$ctl02$ctl00&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="color:Black;">T</a></td>
      <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResults$ctl02$ctl01&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="color:Black;">Party</a></td>
      <td>Opposite Party</td>
      <td style="width:50px;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResults$ctl02$ctl02&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="color:Black;">Type</a></td>
      <td style="width:100px;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResults$ctl02$ctl03&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="color:Black;">Book-Page</a></td>
      <td style="width:70px;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResults$ctl02$ctl04&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="color:Black;">Date</a></td>
      <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResults$ctl02$ctl05&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="color:Black;">Town</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="font-family:Arial;font-size:Smaller;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;">
      <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;">
         <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResults$ctl03$btnView" value="View" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResults_btnView_0" title="Click to view this document" style="width:50px;" />
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;">
         <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResults$ctl03$btnMyDoc" value="My Doc" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResults_btnMyDoc_0" title="Click to add this document to My Documents" style="width:60px;" />
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
         <span title="Click here to select this document"><input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResults_CheckBox1_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResults$ctl03$CheckBox1" /></span>
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
         <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResults_lblParty1_0" title="Grantors:
            ALBERT G MOSES FARM
            MOSES ALBERT G
            Grantees:
            ">MOSES ALBERT G</span>
      </td>
      <td>
         <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResults_lblParty2_0" title="Grantors:
            ALBERT G MOSES FARM
            MOSES ALBERT G
            Grantees:
            "></span>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">MAP</td>
      <td valign="top">- </td>
      <td valign="top">01/16/1953</td>
      <td valign="top">TOWN OF BINGHAMTON</td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="background-color:Gainsboro;font-family:Arial;font-size:Smaller;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;">
      <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;">
         <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResults$ctl04$btnView" value="View*" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResults_btnView_1" title="Click to view this document" style="width:50px;" />
      </td>
      <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;">
         <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResults$ctl04$btnMyDoc" value="My Doc" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResults_btnMyDoc_1" title="Click to add this document to My Documents" style="width:60px;" />
      </td>
      <td valign="top">
         <span title="Click here to select this document"><input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResults_CheckBox1_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdResults$ctl04$CheckBox1" /></span>
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>
         <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResults_lblParty1_1" title="Grantors:
            MOSS EMMY-IND&amp;GDN
            MOSES ALEXANDRA/GDN
            Grantees:
            GOODRICH MERLE L
            GOODRICH CHARITY M
            ">MOSES ALEXANDRA/GDN</span>
      </td>
      <td>
         <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grdResults_lblParty2_1" title="Grantors:
            MOSS EMMY-IND&amp;GDN
            MOSES ALEXANDRA/GDN
            Grantees:
            GOODRICH MERLE L
            GOODRICH CHARITY M
            ">GOODRICH MERLE L</span>
      </td>
</table>
```

This is the script that i have written so far that works for two columns:

```
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = open('searched.html')
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
myTable = bsObj.findAll("tr",{ "style":re.compile("font-family:Arial;font-size:Smaller;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;")} )

 for table_ in myTable:
    party = table_.find("span", {"id": re.compile("Party1_*")})
    oppositeParty= table_.find("span", {"id": re.compile("Party2_*")})
    print(party.get_text()+ "," + oppositeParty.get_text())
```

I have tried doing using children of myTable as follows:

myTable.children

Comment: What specifically are you trying to output? Your question is not complete. It stops after one line of your code. Please come back and edit the question making sure that you include all the relevant information for the question include specifics on what you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried (including properly formatted code), and what the result was (with any error messages and a detailed description of what you got vs what you expected).

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to just dump out the content, something like this should do:

```
myTable = bsObj.find_element_by_tag_name("table")
for table_ in myTable:
    rows = table_.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
    for row_ in rows:
        columns = row_.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
        for column_ in columns:
            # print out comma delimited text of columns...
        # print the end of your row
```

If you're really wanting to scrape specific information, you'll need to provide us with more instructions about what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: According to his locator, `myTable` is actually already the `TR`s.

Comment: good point @JeffC!  (just goes to show how important it is to name your variables accurately).  I've updated my answer to get the table, as well as corrected the method names find_elements_by_tag_name instead of find_element_by_tag_name